# Why are IAuthenticationFilter's methods async?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm implementing a custom `IAuthenticationFilter` for my web application, and the interface requires implementing async methods.  However, my code doesn't actually do anything asynchronously so if I just write the auth code, Visual Studio gives me a warning about the lack of `await` operators for, eg. the `AuthenticateAsync` method.

Why does this interface assume that you will need to do asynchronous work?  Is it an acceptable/sensible workaround to just put my synchronous code inside the lambda of an `await Task.Run(() => {...});`?

Comment: I guess the non-blocking nature of async execution is preferred nowadays. There are Promise libs and async / await for your disposal to handle them in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this interface assume that you will need to do asynchronous work?

It's designed to support async methods in case you're using a persistence layer which provides an async API. It's perfectly fine (in this context) to use a synchronous API from an async context, but you generally cannot (safely) call an async method from a synchronous context. As the first option is a superset of the latter, there's no point in providing two interfaces (e.g. `AuthenticateSync` and `AuthenticateAsync`) when one will do.

Methods that return `Task<T>` do not always need the `async` modifier (even if they have `Async` in the method name) so you can remove the `async` modifier to fix the compiler warnings. You can return a value by using `return Task.FromResult( returnValue )`. In this case `AuthenticateAsync` returns a `Task` so you just need `return Task.CompletedTask;`

So in short: Remove the `async` modifier and perform your normal synchronous, blocking IO inside `AuthenticateAsync` but at the end put `return Task.CompletedTask;` instead of just `return`.

> Is it an acceptable/sensible workaround to just put my synchronous code inside the lambda of an `await Task.Run(() => {...});`?

There is nothing to be gained by using `Task.Run` (as this there is no UI thread in ASP.NET so it's acceptable to block the method while doing a synchronous call).